# Postgres FATAL: hot standby is not possible because wal_level was not set to "replica" or higher on the master server

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am configuring postgres 9.6 on Linux two node (1 master and other is slave)
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-master-slave-replication-with-postgresql-96-on-centos-7/

did all configuration as per note above, master node is running after configuration from note,

but after slave configuration form given note when I starting slave node getting below message in logs on slave side:

```
< 2020-03-17 01:12:07.408 +04 > LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at log time 2020-03-17 00:37:30 +04
< 2020-03-17 01:12:07.408 +04 > HINT:  If this has occurred more than once some data might be corrupted and you might need to choose an earlier recovery target.
< 2020-03-17 01:12:07.420 +04 > LOG:  entering standby mode
< 2020-03-17 01:12:07.422 +04 > WARNING:  WAL was generated with wal_level=minimal, data may be missing
< 2020-03-17 01:12:07.422 +04 > HINT:  This happens if you temporarily set wal_level=minimal without taking a new base backup.
< 2020-03-17 01:12:07.422 +04 > FATAL:  hot standby is not possible because wal_level was not set to "replica" or higher on the master server
< 2020-03-17 01:12:07.422 +04 > HINT:  Either set wal_level to "replica" on the master, or turn off hot_standby here.
< 2020-03-17 01:12:07.423 +04 > LOG:  startup process (PID 20755) exited with exit code 1
< 2020-03-17 01:12:07.423 +04 > LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
< 2020-03-17 01:12:07.425 +04 > LOG:  database system is shut down
```

quite new with postgres and wondering if I missed something or note which I follow is missing something.

Did some google but unfortunately couldn't find anything.

Comment: What does running `show wal_level;` on the primary give you?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response:

output from master is :

-bash-4.2$ psql -c "show wal_level;"
 wal_level
-----------
 replica
(1 row)

Comment: Hello Experts,
Any comments to the issue I am facing please. not able to get over it.

Answer (score 0):

wal_level had to be set to replica or higher at the time you took the base backup.  It looks like you changed wal_level to replica too late.  Throw away your old replica and run pg_basebackup again.

Why are you using 9.6?  If you are just setting things up for the first time, you should be using the latest stable version, 12.

Comment: Hello J,
is postgres version 12 is  available for linux, because using below url shows postgres 10 is highest available for linux and I decided to go release - 1,

Comment: in addition to above statement, 
https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

Comment: From that page, "Please Note: EDB no longer provides Linux installers for PostgreSQL 11 and later versions, and users are encouraged to use the platform-native packages".  I'd never thought of using EDB installers for Linux in the first place, maybe they discontinued them because not many other people did either.  I instead use yum or apt, possibly pointing them to PostgreSQL's own repository.